# How to design for Transient Immunity especially for IEC61000?

Tags: circuit-design, embedded, emc, circuit-protection

I'm working on a PLC project wherein I've to design the protection for transient immunity tests as per IEC61000 standards. I checked in the net regarding deign for EFT,ESD and Transient voltages. I've also read Kennyt book and reading ott book,  Also checking reference designs of TI, Analog devices etc..

Everywhere I'm getting best practices. I need to know the protection devices and filter design calculations also.

Say for example IO of PLC with 24V(IO) and max current of 3A is what designed. What are the calculations for filters and TVS diodes and their position.

can any of you explain in detail about the filter(RC or LC for EFT) and protection devices (For ESD and Transient) with full calculations considering one IO of PLC and one analog In pin. And request you to give me references.
Thanks

Comment: A lot of this isn't "hard science" but domain experience. For example how crappy a 24V supply that can be expected in diverse industrial applications. For mobile applications for example, it can go as high as 30V. TVS needs to be picked with a margin based on the worst case supply. Meaning 33-36V somewhere for mobile applications, but perhaps just 30V for fixed industrial/automation. And you might want to pick a bidirectional TVS in some situations. And so far that's mainly for spikes in the supply rather than ESD from humans.